# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse mac os x

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am running Mac OS X 10.5 and I using eclipse to code my java projects. Eclipse has been running fine until today when I suddenly get the error when I try to run my Main.java:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Main".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I installed Java for Mac OS X 10.5 Update 4 from [this page](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.apple.com/support/downloads/javaformacosx105update1.html) earlier today so I was wondering if that might caused a problem. I have tired reinstalling eclipse (latest version) and find people with similar problems online but have not managed to resolve it. I was wondering if anyone have any idea for a fix?

#### Update:

I first tried to clean up the project through eclipse but this did not work. I then entered the workspace file and removed the already compiled classes, figured it might have to do something with that but that didnt help either. I started a new workspace with a new project and i get the same error.

I then tried to add my owm JRE file manually. What i interesting though is that there is no 1.6.0/Home in the versions folder. But since 1.5.0 did not seem to be added in eclipse I added this from the Versions/1.5.0/Home but I still get the same error. This is starting to become really annoying since I use eclipse atleast 4 hours a day in school.

Maybe my whole java got messed up after the installation of the new Java SE 6? If so how do i revert to only 1.5.0_

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: you can not run *Main.java*. you should run the *Main class* rather.

Comment: I doubt that is what he means... in eclipse you can click on the java file and tell eclipse to run it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your JRE install location has changed due to the update. Go to `Window > Preferences > Installed JREs` and add a new default JRE that points to your updated Java. Then eclipse will rebuild all projects and hopefully, things should be fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project. This [error means](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) that there is a missing `.class` that was there during compilation.

Comment: If you are a maven project, you will want to "Update Project"  (right click project, Maven->Update Project)  This will also clean and rebuild.